# Sencha Touch 2 - TabPanel does not work in MVC designed App

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

simple question for you today...

This works:

```
var carousel = Ext.create('Ext.Carousel', {
            fullscreen: 'true',

            //load in views view clean instantiation using
            // the widget.alias's defined in each view... yea
            // For some reason, putting flex on these components... oh...
            // Have to call directly in by just the xtype since these are just
            // references..
            items: [
                { 
                    xtype: 'Main'
                },
                { 
                    xtype: 'CommentList'
                }                
            ]
```

This does NOT work:

```
var tabpanel = Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
            fullscreen: 'true',
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

            defaults: {
                styleHtmlContent: true
            },

            //load in views view clean instantiation using
            // the widget.alias's defined in each view... yea
            // For some reason, putting flex on these components... oh...
            // Have to call directly in by just the xtype since these are just
            // references..
            items: [
                { 
                    xtype: 'Main',
                    title: 'The Main',
                    iconCls: 'user'
                },
                { 
                    xtype: 'CommentList',
                    title: 'Comments',
                    iconCls: 'user'
                }                
            ]

        });
```

As you can see, they are pretty much the same except one is a TapPanel (with the required default configs added) and the other is a carousel.

Everything else is exactly the same.... This is in the app.js of my Sencha Touch 2.0 app designed following the MVC architecture.

The result of the not-working TabPanel is that I only see the first view (Main) and no tab-bar appears in the bottom of the screen.

Any ideas what my problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is an issue but in my code the line is:

```
Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel", {
```

Not:

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
```

Answer (score 0):

Fullscreen should be `fullscreen: true` instead of `fullscreen: 'true'`. You could also add this code to make them switch:

```
cardSwitchAnimation: {type: "fade", duration: 1000},
layout: "card",
```

Didn't test it, but it worked for me (got it from a snippet of my own code)

Comment: Sencha 2.0 Pr2 doesn't seem to have this cardSwitch config... http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?155784-Tab-Panel-does-not-have-cardSwitchAnimation-config   Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that adding the "card" layout is causing an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setReverse' of null" ... Have you ever seen something like that before?

Comment: I would like to add... I am also getting the error that "Object [object Object] has no method 'getAnimation'" .. this is occuring in the Panel.js file (in the sdk source)... I made sure to add layout: 'card' and cardSwitchAnimation: {type: "fade", duration: 1000}   to the tabpanel but this is the error I get... perhaps there is something basic in the wiring that I am doing wrong?